# How fast cool down a tank of water?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy

I have a tank of water (2000 liter). This is a 1m length 1m width 2m high tank, made of steel.  I heat it up with my furnace to e.g. 50 ºC. I would like to know how quick cool down to 20 ºC (this is my environment temperature) without insulation and with insulation. I do not need accurate calculation, an estimated value/method (minute or hour resolution) is enough for me. The type of the insulation should be a parameter in the equation, because I need to test other materials.

Is it possible to calculate this with pure math or I need to collect some sample, or is it an impossible project?

Comment: What type of material do you want? There are thousands out there in the market.

Comment: Styrofoam and slag wool

Comment: 7-10cm slag wool with 3-5cm styrofoam

Comment: And you need calculations for both conduction and radiation, if I let alone go off convection? That's a bit of work. I don't have time now. I'll do the research and try to post. By then, someone else might help you out!

Comment: I just would like to know that how long can be the temperature of the water over 20C with and without insulation. (I want to use styrofoam and slag wool at the same time). If it's a big work than doesn't matter, not so important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conservative (lowest) estimate can be obtained through [lumped thermal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped_element_model#Newton.27s_law_of_cooling). It basically assumes that the temperature of the cooling object is uniform (no $x$, $y$ or $z$ temperature gradients) during cooling. The alternative is a mathematical nightmare where I won't take you. I'll also ignore radiative losses, which are minor at these temperatures.

Lumped thermal analysis allows to apply [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling), which defines the rate of cooling as a rate of heat energy ($Q$) loss:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=kA[T(t)-T_0]$$

$k$ is a material constant, the so called *heat transfer coefficient* (see below the fold), depending on the insulation (you'll find estimates on many [engineering sites](https://www.engineersedge.com/thermodynamics/overall_heat_transfer-table.htm), depending on insulating material), $A$ the total surface area of your tank, $T_0$ the environment temperature and $T(t)$ the temperature (assumed uniform) inside the tank.

During an infinitesimal drop in temperature $dT$ of the tank:

$$dQ=-mcdT(t)$$

Where $m$ is the mass of the tank and $c$ the specific heat capacity of water.

So, dividing both sides by $dt$, we obtain:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=-mc\frac{dT(t)}{dt}$$

And with the equations above, we get:

$$-mc\frac{dT(t)}{dt}=kA[T(t)-T_0]$$

This differential equation separates into variables easily:

$$\frac{dT(t)}{T(t)-T_0}=-\alpha dt$$

Where:

$$\alpha=\frac{kA}{mc}$$

Integrating gives:

$$\int_{T_1}^{T_2}\frac{dT(t)}{T(t)-T_0}=-\alpha \int_0^t dt$$

Or:

$$\ln \frac{T_2-T_0}{T_1-T_0}=-\alpha t$$

Where $T_1$ is the starting temperature and $T_2$ the end temperature. Note however that when you set $T_2=T_0$ then $t=+\infty$. This is normal and a consequence of Newton's law of cooling.

**So you need to set $T_2$ at a more realistic value, like 95 % of $T_0$, to get some kind of an estimate for your cooling time.**

---

**Heat transfer coefficient $k$:**

In the case of an insulated tank, the heat transfer coefficient is calculated from:

$$\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{h_{surf}}+\frac{\delta_{ins}}{\lambda_{ins}}$$

Here $h_{surf}$ is the *convective heat transfer coefficient* at the surface of the insulation and $\lambda_{ins}$ the heat *conductivity* of the insulation. $\delta_{ins}$ is the latter's thickness.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool thanks! The m is just the mass of the tank without water or it contains the mass of the water too?

Comment: $m$ is the mass of the water. Don't thank: upvote instead! ;-)

Comment: I'll do that from his side.

Comment: @WrichikBasu: well, thank you. Expanded also slightly on the value of $k$.