# Heat Transfer Over Time in a Pipe with Heat Tape Wrapped

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

First time asking a question here so let me know if I leave anything out and thanks in advance for the help!  Really trying to figure out the function over time more than anything else.

I have a 1/4 in(6.35mm OD 4.826mm ID) copper pipe 762cm long with a thickness of .762mm.  With a constant heat applied to the area (.151935 m^2). The liquid inside is water with a volume of 241.32 grams.  The water inside will start at 4.4C and the heat will be a constant 98.9C.  At what time(seconds) will the water inside the pipe reach 76.6C?

Comment: What is a 1/4 copper pipe?

Comment: @ChesterMiller: jargon for 'quarter of an inch', I think.

Comment: So the ID is 0 635 cm, and the wall thickness is 0.0862 cm?  Is that 76.6 C the average temperature or the centerline temperature?

Comment: What you have left out are (1) your attempt to solve the problem yourself, and (2) identification of a conceptual difficulty. These requirements apply to questions asking how to do a calculation. This is not a problem-solving site.

Comment: Sorry about that I may have some incorrect values from the pipe size.  It is 1/4 inch copper pipe.  The 76.6 C will be the average temperature.  The inner diameter of the pipe is .19 inches or 4.826mm.

My attempt to solve the problem is to start with the conduction equation - Q/t=[KA(th-tc)]/d
I have found the K to be 401 for copper.  I then went to solve for Q and then used the equation Q=mCdT to find the change in temp over 1 second.  I think I am missing a step to get to where I can solve for what time the liquid reaches 76.6C.  If you could point me in the direction of the formula

Comment: I think you need to explain what effect "heat tape" has. There are several varieties : is it insulating? or does it supply heat?  I guess you mean that the tape supplies heat while maintaining a constant temperature of 98.9C. (The rate at which heat is supplied is not actually constant, it will fall as the temperature difference falls.)

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  I am building a prototype and am trying to learn the calculations needed.  I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that the heater would change power to hold that temperature.

Comment: @Jacob: have look at this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/367020/how-fast-cool-down-a-tank-of-water/367030#367030 . That's cooling problem but the reasoning is exactly the same as for heating.

Comment: @Gert Thanks!  This is exactly the next step I was looking for.  I will have to figure out the differential equation bit, but that puts me on the next track.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: There is also heat transfer resistance within the water, because the temperature of the water is not going to be uniform.  Whereas, the thermal conductivity of copper is on the order of 400 W/m.K, the thermal conductivity of water is only 0.6 W/m.K.  The heat transfer coefficient on the water side of the boundary is going to be about 8k/D=8(0.6)/(0.004826)=2630 W/m^2.K.  This compares to the heat transfer coefficient through the copper wall of 400/0.000762=525000 W/m^2.K.  So the time ro reach 76.6 C will be 525000/2630 =200 times longer than predicted by @Gert's equation.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: you too are oversimplifying. I assume the temperature to be uniform inside the object because the alternative is mathematically very demanding, as I'm sure you are aware. But it's possible to account for water's poor thermal conductivity by choosing a realistic *convective heat transfer coefficient* for the water layer next to the copper boundary.  That's an '"engineer's approach". But that too is an approximation, of course...

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  I just watched some videos about differentials(still need to learn more about them)  I have a result of 23.9 seconds.  I am not sure if I lost a decimal place due to using grams or kilograms.  Is this close or am I a few places off?

Comment: I get 10x as long = 235 seconds = 4 minutes

Comment: @Gert I used the asymptotic heat transfer coefficient, determined from the solution to the transient heat conduction equation within the water to account for the heat transfer resistance of the water; this is a lower bound to the actual heat transfer coefficient, and thus provides a conservative upper bound (but close upper bound) to the heating time.  Also, to be conservative, the solution also neglects natural convection within this tiny diameter duct, which can't be important.  The solution to this problem is dominated by the water resistance, and not by the resistance of the copper wall.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: you should formulate it as an answer! ;-)

Comment: @ChesterMiller: what do you mean by the *" asymptotic heat transfer coefficient"*?

Comment: I'm going to formulate it as an answer.  In the meantime, have you actually used the equation in your solution (neglecting heat transfer resistance in the water) to calculate the heating time for this problem?

Comment: @Gert You're aware that you do not need to have convection to make use of the heat transfer coefficient concept, correct?  In this analysis, I'm determining the heat transfer coefficient for conductive transfer of heat into the water within the tube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we neglect natural convection heat transfer within the liquid water, the present problem can by regarded as transient conductive heat transfer to a solid circular cylinder.  Because of the very low thermal conductivity of water compared to the copper tube wall, the dominant resistance to heat transfer in this system is going to reside primarily within the water.  However, in the present analysis, we will include both resistances, so that we can compare.

In transient heat transfer to a cylinder, the heat transfer coefficient (defined as the instantaneous wall heat flux divided by the instantaneous difference between the wall temperature and average cylinder temperature) starts out very high initially, but then gradually decreases to a final asymptotic value at long times, as the radial temperature profile within the cylinder approaches a final shape, roughly resembling a parabola.  So, the instantaneous heat transfer coefficient on the water side of the wall is always greater than this asymptotic heat transfer coefficient. If this asymptotic heat transfer coefficient were assumed to prevail, not just at long times, but at all times, one would obtain an upper bound to the heating time for the cylinder. In reality, one finds that the asymptotic heat transfer coefficient typically provides a good approximation over most practical  times, particularly when the final average temperature is closer to the wall temperature than to the initial temperature.  This is the situation that prevails in the present analysis, and thus, we employ the asymptotic heat transfer coefficient. Thus, the present result will provide a close upper bound to the true heating time.

The asymptotic heat transfer coefficient for transient heat transfer to a cylinder, obtained from the analytic solution to the transient heat conduction equation for a cylinder, is given by the equation:  $$h_w=\frac{8k_w}{D}$$ where $h_w$ is the subscript w on h refers to the water side of the boundary, $k_w$ is the thermal conductivity of water, and D is the ID of the tube.  The heat transfer coefficient for conduction through the copper tube wall is given by $$h_c=\frac{k_c}{\delta}$$where the subscript c refers to the copper tube, $k_c$ is the thermal conductivity of copper, and $\delta$ is the tube wall thickness.  Since the copper resistance and the water resistance are in series, the overall heat transfer coefficient h is given by:$$\frac{1}{h}=\frac{1}{k_w}+\frac{1}{k_c}$$

From these equations, we obtain:  $$h=\frac{8k_w/D}{\left(1+\frac{8k_w\delta}{k_cD}\right)}$$

From a transient heat balance on the water cylinder, we have that:

$$\rho C\frac{\pi D^2}{4}\frac{dT}{dt}=\pi Dh(T_0-T) $$
where $\rho$ is the density of water, C is the heat capacity of water, $T_0$ is the temperature at the outside surface of the copper duct, and T is the average water temperature.  If we combine and simplify the previous equations, we obtain:$$\frac{dT}{dt}=\frac{(T_0-T)}{\tau}$$ where the characteristic time $\tau$ is given by $$\tau=\frac{D^2}{32\alpha_w}\left(1+\frac{8k_w\delta}{k_cD}\right)$$with $\alpha_w$ representing the thermal diffusivity of water $\frac{k_w}{\rho C}$.

The solution to the differential equation for the average temperature is given by:  $$\ln{\frac{(T_0-T)}{(T_0-T_i})}=-\frac{t}{\tau}$$
For the present problem parameters, one finds that $$\frac{8k_w\delta}{k_cD}=0.005$$indicating that resistance to heat transfer on the water side of the wall is much higher than the resistance through the copper wall.  The value of the characteristic time $\tau$ is calculated to be 163 seconds.  The time required for the average water temperature to reach 76.6 C is calculated to be about 4 minutes.

Comment: Nice answer. +1.

Comment: Have you got a decent reference for  $h_w=\frac{8k_w}{D}$?

Comment: @ Gert The following link analyzes the problem of heat transfer to a fluid in plug flow (flat velocity profile):  https://www.syvum.com/cgi/online/serve.cgi/eng/heat/heat1007.html  The analysis makes the usual assumption that axial heat conduction is negligible, so that the problem is equivalent mathematically to radial conductive heat transfer to a cylinder (with x/v = t).  The analysis is for the case of a constant wall heat flux, but I know from experience that the asymptotic Nussult number for this case is only slightly different from that for constant wall temperature.

Comment: Hey guys, I have been looking to find a way to heat the liquid in the pipe faster than 4 minutes.  Would adding a flow to the pipe increase the transfer rate at all?  or is the only option to flatten the pipe to increase surface area?  I'm learning, just a little slower than I would like!  The reason I ask is I want to heat 8 to 12 ounces at a time.  If this should be a diff question I'll move it to a new spot

Comment: Can you please provide more detail on what you have in mind?

Comment: Sure, I was thinking of adding a recirculating pump to move/agitate the water inside the pipe.  
If that wasn't enough I was considering flattening the pipe to reduce the volume per unit of length.  Then I would add more length to account for the reduced volume.  I was reading that counterflow exchangers were more efficient so thats where the idea of moving the fluid to reduce the time to temp came from.